# A fairytale movie with couple meeting in dreams

Tags: story-identification, fairy-tales

I recently remembered a movie I watched about 15 years ago as a kid, and have been trying to find out the name without luck.

What I remember about it:

- I think it was like a fairytale.
- It was about a couple meeting only in shared dreams, in a garden.
- The boy was a prince.
- The girl I think was living with a witch or wizard who tries to stop her.
- I think the movie was in Italian, but not too sure.
- They get to meet once a year in dreams only.
- It was live-action, not animated.

Comment: Live action or animated? You watched it 15 years ago but was it a recent release, or possibly older (basically, when would it have been released)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Ibbetson is a partial match, but doesn't match enough to post as an answer.

Comment: Also not *On Body and Soul*

Comment: You might look to see if anything on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Films_about_dreams looks familiar.

Comment: @Jenayah It was live-action.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots Went through the list reading the plots, none of them match

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems like "[Sorellina e il principe del sogno](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0116613/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)" (TV Movie, 1996)

> Alisea and her brothers have been captured by Azaret, an evil wizard. Alisea escapes the castle and meets the young Prince Demian, with whom she falls in love. The spirit of the source promises that they will always be together if they are to drink from its source. Alisea is again caught by the magician, and Demian has to return to his father's cone, which aims to turn him into a warrior. Seven years later, Demian becomes a warrior, but has not forgotten Alisea, who he sees in his dreams. Azaret tries to prevent Demian and Alisea from begin together.

### Preview Trailer

Found it with a Google search for `prince dates in his dreams movie`

Comment: Well found! Was that one you were already familiar? Or did you search for it? If the latter, what was your search process?

Comment: That's the oneeee. Thank you @Yaroslav Kornachevskyi :)

Comment: @FuzzyBoots it was the google search: prince dates in his dreams movie

Comment: I guess "begin" at the end is a typo for "being".